# escape `link_to` return value for sending over ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my helper function:

```
def edit_and_delete_links_for(model)
    model_route_path = model.class.to_s.downcase
    if policy(model).update?
        links = link_to "Edit", self.send("edit_#{model_route_path}_path", model), class: 'btn btn-primary edit-btn'
        if current_user.admin?
            links += link_to "Delete", self.send("#{model_route_path}_path", model), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger destroy-btn"
        end
    end
    return links
end
```

I am trying to use this in my ajax results

**next.json.rb**

```
{
    "library" : <%= ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@library).serializable_hash.to_json.html_safe %>,
    "links": {
        "language" : "<%= language_path(@library.language) %>",
        "framework" : "<%= framework_path(@library.framework) %>"
    },
    "buttons": "<%= edit_and_delete_links_for(@library).to_s %>"
}
```

For some reason it will not escape the `"` marks around the class as you can see from what chrome marks me getting:

```
{
    "library" : {"id":5,"version":null,"average_rating":"2.0","vote_count":1,"comment_count":0,"description":"Simple ORM for Sinara and Rails","reviews":[{"id":5,"rating":2,"comment":null,"user_name":"first!","updated_at":" 5:04pm on 2017-07-16 (UTC)"}]},
    "links": {
        "language" : "/languages/1",
        "framework" : "/frameworks/2"
    },
    "buttons": "<a class="btn btn-primary edit-btn" href="/libraries/5/edit">Edit</a>"
}
```

Any ideas how to escape this. I have tried `json_escape` and it did nothing. I believe the issue is because it is marked as html_safe but I have not been able to find a way to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `escape_javascript` (or `j`) when calling `edit_and_delete_links_for` method in your view:

```
"buttons": "<%= j edit_and_delete_links_for(@library).to_s %>"
```

Or, as an alternative, you could use simple quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) in your view, like this:

```
"buttons": '<%= edit_and_delete_links_for(@library).to_s %>'
```

Comment: I can't escape them in link_to and I tried using ' and rails just replaced them with "

Comment: @MHornbacher Can you share `edit_and_delete_links_for` method?

Comment: @MHornbacher I was wrong, you **can** escape them on the view; check the updated answer.